# How to Get ViewModel From SelectedTab in ZK?

Tags: mvvm, zk, zul

I have a toolBar where i am using plenty of item now when i am clicking on any item i am creating a tab.Something like this code

```
public static void openNewTab(String title, String path, Tabbox mainTab) {
    Tab tab = new Tab(title);
    tab.setClosable(true);
    tab.setParent(mainTab.getTabs());
    Tabpanel tabpanel = new Tabpanel();
    Include include = new Include(path);
    include.setParent(tabpanel);
    tabpanel.setParent(mainTab.getTabpanels());
    mainTab.setSelectedTab(tab);
}
```

Now i will want to get the ViewModel of selected tab When any Ctrl Key press in ZUL...
I have this

```
@Wire("#mainTab")
Tabbox mainTab;
   Tab tab = mainTab.getSelectedTab( );
```

Can it possible to get ViewModel from the selectedTab varaibles?

And i am doing like this

```
Include include = new Include(path);
include.setParent(tabpanel);
Object object = include.getAttribute("viewModel");
```

Now object is giving null Can we get ViewModel from here while i am including a ZUl here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the id is the attribute name to get vm, see [sample at zkfiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2dj3bmj/3-Get-binder-and-vm-from-component)

Btw "binder" is the attribute name to get binder, for more information please refer to [Source code of binder](https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zkbind/src/org/zkoss/bind/BindComposer.java)

You can also try to use Component.getAttributes to get the attribute map and check all attributes in it, see [Javadoc: Component#getAttributes](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Component.html#getAttributes%28%29)